# (bsnmpd), uid 0: exited on signal 6 (core dumped) / Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "then")

Tags: cron, freebsd, shell, snmpd

I'm using FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD f9.alexus.org 9.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE #0 r255898: Thu Sep 26 22:50:31 UTC 2013     root@bake.isc.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
#
```

every once in a while `bsnmpd(1)` is producing following message for me:

```
# bzip2 -cd /var/log/all.log.0.bz2 | grep bsnmpd
Oct 12 21:01:44 f9 kernel: pid 62584 (bsnmpd), uid 0: exited on signal 6 (core dumped)
#
```

I *REALLY* would like to figure out what's the causing it, but meanwhile:

```
# crontab -l | grep @hourly
@hourly     `which service` bsnmpd status >/dev/null ; if ( $? != 0 ) `which service` bsnmpd start ; endif
#
```

I keep getting email w/ following message:

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "then")
```

test (via shell):

```
# `which service` bsnmpd status >/dev/null ; if ( $? != 0 ) `which service` bsnmpd start ; endif
# /etc/rc.d/bsnmpd stop
Stopping bsnmpd.
Waiting for PIDS: 60671.
# /etc/rc.d/bsnmpd status
bsnmpd is not running.
# `which service` bsnmpd status > /dev/null ; if ( $? != 0 ) `which service` bsnmpd start ; endif
Starting bsnmpd.
# /etc/rc.d/bsnmpd status
bsnmpd is running as pid 61042.
#
```

1. How can I debug what's causing `bsnmpd(1)` to exit at the first place?
2. What's wrong w/ my cronjob?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the cron job to look more like this:

```
/usr/sbin/service bsnmpd status >/dev/null ; if [ $? != 0 ] ; then /usr/sbin/service bsnmpd start ; fi
```

Anyway, let's figure out why bsnmpd is core dumping. See if you can find the `bsnmpd.core` file, then run `/usr/bin/gdb /usr/sbin/bsnmpd bsnmpd.core` then run `bt` and paste the output.

Comment: please see : http://pastebin.com/U6tr0GHS

Comment: Could you share your snmp configs, if any?

Comment: I'm using default /etc/snmpd.conf that came w/ FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE `# $FreeBSD: release/9.2.0/etc/snmpd.config 216595 2010-12-20 17:28:15Z syrinx $` (w/out any modifications)

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what SNMP requests are being made? Perhaps there's some particular request that triggers the SIGABRT?

Comment: I'm using `mrtg-2.17.4_4,1`, so all requests comes from that and most of the time everything works fine (as I can see it via web page) yet every once in a while `bsnmpd` and produce `/bsnmpd.core` file.